# Mac Disk Utility Undo volume scheme change

Tags: mac, partitioning, data-recovery, disk-utility

My sister made a mistake when trying to reformat a hard drive, and buggered up a hard drive with her work on it.  She says it happened very quickly which leads me to believe she's actually just changed the header of the drive, but that the disk contents may still be intact.

In disk utility she selected the drive and then selected the partition tab at the top.  She then selected a volume scheme of one partition.  Then at the bottom of the volume box she chose options and selected a GUID partition table.  She then hit apply.

I'm wondering if there's a way for her to get her old partition table back?  Probably not, but it seems to me like the data should still be intact on the drive.  Will a standard data recovery tool work here?